# JavaScript mouseover

Tags: javascript

I built home page takeover for an ad spot. My problem: The mouse pointer does not change when I mouse over the background area.  Any ideas on how to do this?  My code is below...the link works but the mouse over does not:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
$(document).click(function(e){
        if(e.target.nodeName == "HTML" || e.target.nodeName == "BODY"){
         document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
     window.open('http://www.google.com/');
   }
})
   })
 })(jQuery);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with CSS:

```
element {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/eRxXD/)

Comment: Thanks. The problem Im having is that the background image is loaded using CSS and I need to make it clickable only when the mouse is over the ad spots: see the webpage http://www.ultimatemotorcycling.com

Comment: You can place some empty divs in the relevant areas, give those the cursor styling and link handling. Or you could style some a elements to do the same job and get proper right and middle click support.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and help!  Im going to try to figure it out using JavaScript